# Pointer to pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

Can someone explain the output of the following code

```
char* a[] = {"ABC123", "DEF456", "GHI789"};
char **p = a;
cout<<++*p<<std::endl;
cout<<*p++<<std::endl;
cout<<++*p<<std::endl;
```

Output:

```
BC123
BC123
EF456
```

What is confusing to me is the different behavior of ++*p and *p++. I was expecting the output to be:

```
ABC123
DEF456
GHI789
```

Comment: Operator precedence. Add some parentheses and it'll come clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* a[] = {"ABC123", "DEF456", "GHI789"};
char **p = a;
cout<<++*p<<std::endl; // 1
cout<<*p++<<std::endl; // 2
cout<<++*p<<std::endl; // 3
```

On line 1 first `*p` will be pointing to the element in the array `"ABC123"` and the `++` moves one forward and so 'BC123' is printed.

On line 2 `*p` is still pointing to `BC123` so this is printed and then once printed the `++` is carried out. This moves the pointer to the 2nd element in the array

On line 3 it is the same as line 1. You have taken the contents of `p` (Now the 2nd element in the array) and moved one character in that string, thus printing `EF456`

(Also have a look at here [Pointer arithmetic on string type arrays, how does C++ handle this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006172/pointer-arithmetic-on-string-type-arrays-how-does-c-handle-this) as I think it might be useful to get an understanding of what is happening)

To print what you expected the following would work:

```
cout<<*p++<<std::endl;
cout<<*p++<<std::endl;
cout<<*p++<<std::endl;
```

Or

```
cout<<*p<<std::endl;
cout<<*(++p)<<std::endl;
cout<<*(++p)<<std::endl;
```

Or various other ways (taking into account precedence as others have said)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this will help. You example is roughly equivalent to this:

```
++(*p);
cout << *p << '\n';

cout << *p << '\n';
++p;

++(*p);
cout << *p << '\n';
```

Without parentheses, `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)` since suffix increment has got higher precedence than dereference operator. Increment is still done after the whole expression, though.

On the other hand, prefix increment and * have got same precedence, so `++*p` is parsed right-to-left as `++(*p)`. Knowing that prefix increment has to be done before the expression, you can now put the whole picture together.

Comment: I got it... I was only taking operator precedence into picture, forgetting completely about the associativity.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to C++ operator precedence table, precedence of post-increment is higher than dereference (*) operator, and pre-increment and dereference operator have same precedence. Also pre-increment and dereference operator are right-to-left associative.

So in the first line (`cout<<++*p<<std::endl;`), * and ++ are evaluated from right to left (first dereference, then increment). Now `p` still point to the first array (because it has not changed),but (*p) points to the second letter of the first string (the output shows this fact).

In second line (`cout<<*p++<<std::endl;`) however post-increment is evaluated first (after retrieving the old value of `p`) and the `p` is incremented and now points to the second array. But before increment, the value of p is used in the expression and output of the second line is exactly as the first line.

In third line, first the `p` is dereferenced (point to the first letter of the second array), then incremented (point to the second letter of the second array), and the value is printed.

Answer (score 0):

`++*p` is executed before printing. So increment pointer, then print.
`*p++` is executed after printing. Print, then increment.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think because you are incrementing the deferenced pointer using `cout<<++*p<<std::endl;`, what you are actually doing is incrementing the character at the start of the string that p points to then outputting this to the standard output.

Similarly `cout<<*p++<<std::endl;` is incrementing the character after outputting so the final `cout<<++*p<<std::endl;` results in two increments.

You should try this instead and see if it works

```
cout<<*(++p)<<std::endl; 
cout<<*(p++)<<std::endl; 
cout<<*(++p)<<std::endl;
```

Comment: The last line of that output causes it to go boom unfortunately. The `++p` is moving it to beyond the end of the array